# Multiple images fail to display using data URI: silent browser bug

Tags: javascript

It's one of those silent browser bugs where the browser refuses to execute the full request. The code below (just make a file called example.xhtml to test it out, make sure you don't have a byte order mark by using Microsoft based editors) is all the working code. When you select multiple images it only displays one of the images in Firefox, Opera and Chrome.

Would someone explain the silent bug issue in detail (which I've gotten around by using setTimeOut in previous situations)?

**example.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Image Preview</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = function(e)
{
 var thumb = document.createElement('img');
 thumb.setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
 document.getElementById('images_preview').appendChild(thumb);
}


function images_preview()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('post_files').files.length; i++)
 {
  var f = document.getElementById('post_files').files[i];
  fr.readAsDataURL(f);
 }
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
 <input id="post_files" name="post_files" multiple="multiple" onchange="images_preview();" size="256" type="file" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="images_preview"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the *onloadend* method is what I needed. Here is a fully fixed/working version of what I coded above...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title>Image Preview</title>
<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function images_preview()
{
 for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('post_files').files.length; i++)
 {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  var dataurl = fr.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('post_files').files[i]);

  fr.onloadend = function(e)
  {
   var thumb = document.createElement('img');
   thumb.setAttribute('src',e.target.result);
   document.getElementById('images_preview').appendChild(thumb);
  }
 }
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
 <input id="post_files" name="post_files" multiple="multiple" onchange="images_preview();" size="256" type="file" />
</fieldset>
</form>

<div id="images_preview"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your trouble comes from trying to reuse the reader before it is done processing a file. Too bad the browsers silently ignore the problem. Anyhow, if you use a new reader for each file, like in the following Mozilla documentation [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example%3a_Showing_thumbnails_of_user-selected_images), you should be ok:

```
function handleFiles(files) {  
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {  
    var file = files[i];  
    var imageType = /image.*/;  

    if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {  
      continue;  
    }  

    var img = document.createElement("img");  
    img.classList.add("obj");  
    img.file = file;  
    preview.appendChild(img);  

    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);  
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);  
  }  
}
```

Comment: You were close, turns out I needed to use the onloadend method. I posted my answer above.